# Value Javascript Input

Tags: javascript, html, input, string-concatenation

how can i transfer the Value from Input 1 in 2 and add some letters?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function doit(){
document.getElementById('input2').value=document.getElementById('input1').value;
}

</script>
```

Input1: 2342

Input2: pcid2342d

Can some one help me?

Comment: Your attempt looks good. Does it not work?

Comment: The code appears to be mostly correct. What errors are you getting? What is not working?

Comment: there are no errors, it was that i don't know how to add letters on the string :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the + operator to add a string before and after the input value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function doit(){
document.getElementById('input2').value="pcid" + document.getElementById('input1').value + "d";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation:

```
document.getElementById('input2').value = "stuff" + document.getElementById('input1').value + "other stuff";
```

When dealing with numbers you could start by concatenating with empty string to avoid adding numbers together instead of concatenating to strings (because of operator evaluation order):

```
document.getElementById('input2').value = "" + 1234 + 567 + document.getElementById('input1').value + 89;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you seem to have done the work already, all you need is something to click on to execute it:

```
<button onclick="doit()">click me</button>
```

Comment: i have an other input with onload so i don't need a button, but thanks^^

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something in jQuery?

```
  $("#Anything").click(function() {
     $("#Field1").val($("#Field2").val());
  });
```

The "click" is just a assumption =)

Comment: For such a trivial task Jquery is overkill I think!